# Logical relevance of lebesgue's integration

Tags: lebesgue-integral

I have been trying to make sense of the existence of two integration theories, that of Riemann and Lebesgue. The latter integrates the Dirichlet function and assigns a value 1, while the former theory cannot integrate the function. What is integration and what does the value of integral mean? Should it be understood as the existence of a linear functional with good limit-properties on as large a class of functions as possible? Given this discrepancy between Riemann's theory and Lebesgue's theory, how does it turn out that by applying both the theories one gets, for instance, that the sum of reciprocals of squares of integers is equal to $\pi^2/6$?

The notion of 'powerful' theory in algebra is related to the ability to solve more and more complicated questions, by discovering new notions and their relationships.  But analysis seems to me to include 'choice' between two theories to solve a problem, in which case what does it mean to solve a problem in analysis?

I am sorry if I am not able to put forth my questions clearly.

Comment: FYI, there are dozens integration theories. A few of the better known ones are discussed in [**The Integrals of Lebesgue, Denjoy, Perron, and Henstock**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0821838059) by Russell A. Gordon (1994). For many, many more see: Peter Bullen, [*Non-absolute integrals in the twentieth century*](https://www.emis.de/proceedings/Toronto2000/papers/bullen.pdf), AMS Special Session on Nonabsolute Integration, 23-24 September 2000, 27 pages (195 references) **(continued)**

Comment: *AND* Ralph Henstock, *A short history of integration theory*, **Southeast Asian Bulletin of Mathematics** 12 #2 (1988), 75-95 (262 references; might be available [here](http://www.seams-bull-math.ynu.edu.cn/downloadfile.jsp?filemenu=_198802&filename=198802_1530365150482.tar) as a compressed .TIFF scan).